# Generator of $\mathbb Z^*_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p=2^8+1=257$. Show that $g=3$ generates the group $\mathbb Z^*_p$.

Answer (score 3):

A general procedure for verifying that an element $g$ alone generates a given group $G$ emerges from the following points:

1. Find the order $n$ of $G$. Here it is $p-1$.
2. Factor $n$ completely (this may be difficult in some cases).
3. By Lagrange's theorem the order of $g$ is a factor of $n$. Therefore to prove that $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)=n$ it suffices to show that the equation $g^d=1$ is not satisfied by any proper factor $d\mid n, d<n$.
4. If the prime factorization of $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then it is sufficient to do the verification of item 3 for the choices $d=n/p_i, i=1,2,\ldots,k$. If you have not seen this before, you should justify this. Hint: show that any proper factor $d$ of $n$ is also a factor of at least one of the numbers $n/p_i, i=1,2,\ldots,k$.
5. When computing highish powers of $g$, [the good ole' square-and-multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is your friend.